# My function is confused about whether or not it wants a second argument (python, matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm writing a (should be) simple program in Python using Tkinter and Matplotlib to control a machine.  It's my first Python program, so apologies for any egregious non-conventions, and I welcome all feedback.  Also, sorry for the large code block.

I'm trying to have a main page for controls, and a secondary page that shows up with a graph while the machine is performing a run.  I've managed to get the second page to show up and go away properly, and show the graph.  However, every time it adds a point to the graph, it yells at me about

```
> 
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 585, in callit
    func(*args)
TypeError: graph_animate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'i'
```

So I removed the ", i" argument from my graph function so it only takes (self), then it yelled at me in a different manner:

```
> 
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 381, in show
    manager = getattr(self.canvas, 'manager')
AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasTkAgg' object has no attribute 'manager
```

followed by a bunch of locations within files and modules, ending with:

```
> 
....File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1212, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
TypeError: graph_animate() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I'm not very familiar with troubleshooting in Python, but it seems like a catch-22 type deal where I specify another argument and it says I don't have it, so I take it out and it says it's got too many.  I spent a fair amount of time trying to figure out what was going on, and how constructors are specified in tkinter, but I still couldn't fix the error.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import datetime
import time
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, StringVar
import urllib
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

f = Figure()
a = f.add_subplot(111)
gsFurnaceTemp = 0
plottime = []
plottemp = []

class BrokeApp:
    global gsFurnaceTemp
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.myParent=parent
        self.root=parent

        self.myContainer1=tk.Frame(parent)
        self.myContainer1.pack()

        label = tk.Label(self.myContainer1, text = "My Broken App")
        label.grid(columnspan=4)
        buttonStart=tk.Button(self.myContainer1, text="Start Run",
                              bg='green', height=3, width=20,
                              command = self.btnStartClick)
        buttonStart.grid(row=7, column=1)

        self.ChillerLabelText = StringVar()
        self.ChillerLabelText.set(gsFurnaceTemp)
        lblChillerTemp = tk.Label(self.myContainer1, textvariable=self.ChillerLabelText)
        lblChillerTemp.grid(row=100, column=100)

        self.getDataTimer()

    def btnStartClick(self):
        self.newWindow=tk.Toplevel(self.myParent)
        self.app=GraphPage(self.newWindow)

    def getDataTimer(self):
        gsFurnaceTemp=open("TempTxt.txt", "r").read()
        self.ChillerLabelText.set(str(gsFurnaceTemp))
        self.root.after(1000, self.getDataTimer)


class GraphPage:
    global gsFurnaceTemp
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.myParent=parent
        self.root=parent
        self.master=parent

        self.plottempz = []
        self.plottimez = []
        self.fz = Figure()
        self.az = self.fz.add_subplot(111)

        self.myContainer1=tk.Frame(parent)
        self.myContainer1.pack()

        label = tk.Label(self.myContainer1, text = "Temp Graph")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        btnStartPage = ttk.Button(self.myContainer1, text="Back to Main Page",
                           command = self.close_Window)
        btnStartPage.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fz, self.myContainer1)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack() 

        plottemp= []
        plottime= []

        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fz, self.graph_animate, interval=1000)
        self.fz.show()


    def graph_animate(self, i):  #THIS IS THE LOCATION WHERE I REMOVE AND
                                 #INSERT THE ", i" WHICH HAS BEEN GIVING ME TROUBLES
        gsFurnaceTemp=open("TempTxt.txt", "r").read()
        plottemp.append(gsFurnaceTemp)
        self.az.clear()
        self.az.plot(plottemp)

        self.root.after(1000, self.graph_animate)

        gsFurnaceTemp=open("TempTxt.txt", "r").read()

    def close_Window(self):
        self.master.destroy()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = BrokeApp(root)
    root.geometry("800x600")
    root.mainloop()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also, sorry if any of this code is redundant or any of my declared variables are unused.  My brain is fairly fried just from figuring out how to condense it into a sufficiently short, yet compilable chunk from the larger program.

Steeeeeve

Comment: I'm having errors even running it, with no error message, which is severely confusing me since I've never seen Python crash without an error message before.   Maybe the contents of `TempTxt.txt` would help?

Comment: The contents of that file were just:  "125"  without quotes.  I tried different numbers and they all worked, and I could graph the numbers, but not without throwing the error about "you need to specify i"

Answer (score 1):

That i must be defined, you can check how 'frames' work in FuncAnimation. I will suggest you to read the documentation about matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.